# Custom name for pdf print in Odoo 14?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Hi all i am trying to change the file name of pdf print. I tried below two methods.

```
<report
            id="daily_invoice_report_print_menu"
            model="account.move"
            string="Invoice Print 12334"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="daily_report.daily_invoice_report_template"
            file="daily_report.daily_invoice_report_template"
            print_report_name = "(('Sales Invoice '+ object.name or 'Print').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
    menu="False"/>

    <record id="daily_invoice_report_print_menu" model="ir.actions.report">
        <field name="name">Invoice Print 12334</field>
        <field name="model">daily.transaction.report</field>
        <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
        <field name="report_name">daily_report.daily_invoice_report_template</field>
        <field name="print_report_name">'(object.name+'.pdf')'</field>

    </record>
```

but still showing the file name as Invoice Print 1234

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Odoo uses the field `print_report_name` to change the name of the printed file,
but this only possibly only for one record at a time, so if you select multiple records odoo will ignore this as you can see here:

```py
if docids:
       ids = [int(x) for x in docids.split(",")]
       obj = request.env[report.model].browse(ids)
       if report.print_report_name and not len(obj) > 1:
          report_name = safe_eval(report.print_report_name, {'object': obj, 'time': time})
          filename = "%s.%s" % (report_name, extension)
```

Comment: Charif DZ thanks to the reply. but I didn't understand completely. How can I change the value of print name? in the above code snippet also considering the print_report_name, right?

Comment: What do you mean? when you select only one record and print it the file name is not generated correctly?

Comment: Not that, actually i am trying to print the report from a wizard, in that wizard I can choose one customer. i need that customer name as a file name, this is what I need. Is it possible?